# Monitor changes in user entry

Tags: android

I need a method that can monitor each change in the user in an `EditText`. To be more specific the `EditText` in the `SearchDialog`. Is there any such method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
                                      //do something
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
                                     //do something
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do I do this for SearchDialog